# Tangent space of a vector bundle at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-spaces

Let $Y$ be a submanifold of a smooth manifold $X$. Let $NY \rightarrow Y$ denotes the normal bundle of $X$ m, I've read that at a point $y \in Y$, we have $T_y(NY)= T_yY \oplus N_yY$, how can we prove this ?

Is there a generalization of this result to an arbitrary vector bundle, i.e if $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle with fiber $F$, and  $x \in M$, do we have $T_xE = T_{\pi(x)} M \oplus T_x F $?

Comment: Are you familiar with the equivalence $T_{(x,y)}(X\times Y)\cong T_xX\oplus T_yY$ for manifolds $X,Y$? Are you also familiar with the equivalence $T_vV\cong V$ where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: @Kajelad, thanks for your comment and sorry for my late response to it. Actually, yes I am familiar with these two facts and I can conclude from them what is the tangent space of a trivial bundle at a point but still I don't know what happen if the vector bundle is not trivial!

Comment: For a nontrivial bundle, just use a local trivializations. Note that $T_xE$ and $T_{\pi(x)}M\oplus F$ are isomorphic, but there is no canonical choice of isomorphism.

Comment: @Kajelad , could you please elaborate further how to use local trivializations to conclude that $T_xE$ is isomorphic to $T_{\pi(x)}M \oplus F$ ?

Comment: Given $x\in E$, choose a local trivialization around $x$, which is a diffeomorphism from a neighborhood of $x$ to a neighborhood of $M\times F$. From there, just apply the argument for product spaces.

Comment: I got it now! The point I was missing is that the tangent space of an open set in $E$ at a point is equal to the tangent space of $E$ at this point ...thanks a lot  for your help @Kajelad !